# AnythingSlider Hover on external links (MouseMove) also have ahref link?

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, mousemove, anythingslider

I'd like to use AnythingSlider that allows you to navigate by hovering over external links. But I'd like those external "nav" links to have a link to a different page. So the hover function moves the slider but when you click the 1-5 they direct you to a different page (like page1.html, page2.html, page3.html etc...). See my jsfiddle for example:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
buildNavigation: false,
buildStartStop: false,
buildArrows: false
});

$('ul.nav a').bind('mousemove', function() {
var h = this.hash;
// external links will fall through and go to the external url
if (/#\d/.test(h)) {
    $('#slider').anythingSlider(h.substring(1));
    return false;
}
});

<ul id="slider">
<li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placebear.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="http://placedog.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I'd like the nav area to also have links (but also activate the hover slider progression):

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="1.html">1</a></li>
<li><a href="2.html">2</a></li>
<li><a href="3.html">3</a></li>
<li><a href="4.html">4</a></li>
<li><a href="5.html">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58Qmg/

To reiterate: Is there anyway to have the hover function move the sliders, but also have the li ahref (onclick) bring the user to another page? Make sense?

Comment: I guess I could just use a li onlick like this:
<li onclick="location.href='ebay.com'"><a href="#1">1</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional attribute to the link like `data-slide` and read that instead of the `href`. I also removed the `return false` to make the link clickable again. Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/58Qmg/5/):

```
$('ul.nav a').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    // get slide number
    var h = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    // external links will fall through and go to the external url
    if (h) {
        $('#slider').anythingSlider(h);
    }
});​
```

Please note that because jsFiddle doesn't allow you to open other web pages in the frame, I added a `target="_blank"` to each link:

```
<a data-slide="1" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">1</a>
```